# LINQ : How to check CONTAINS with multiple dynamic input values

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am facing a problem regarding a LINQ query.

I have multiple input values which is stored in List< string > variable.

I have to form a LINQ query which would have a where clause which check for the respective column with CONTAINS keyword. The issue I am facing is that List< string > can contain any number of values in it.

So i want to know how can i form a query which can read input values from collection object. and display the result.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand the question properly, do you mean something like Select * from t where col in ('1','2'); , or could you please post some code of what you tried so far and what you want

Comment: Do you mean that you need to see if 1. a column contains a value (in this case do you have just one column to check or multiple) or 2. if a table contains a column ? Is your List<string> effectively a list of column names or expected values in a column (or in one of a known set of columns) ?

Comment: This is the one I have found best on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/57625279

Answer (score 2):

Linq extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Collection, IEnumerable<T> Values)
{
     return Collection.Any(x=> Values.Contains(x));
}
```

Then you can use like:

```
List<string> List1 = getStringList1();
List<string> List2 = getStringList2();

bool List2ItemsInList1 = List1.ContainsAny(List2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Suppose you have three values X, Y and Z. If you want to fetch the results where a Column is either X, Y or Z, then habib-osu's answer will do this.

If you are looking for all records where a particular column contains X, Y and Z then the following should work

```
List<string> options = new List<string>();
options.Add("X");
options.Add("Y");
options.Add("Z");

var query = (from r in dc.Table select r); 
foreach(var option in options)
   query = (from r in query where r.Column.Contains(option) select r);

var list = query.ToList();
```

This will produce one sql query similar to the following

```
select * from Table where Column like '%X%' and column like '%Y%' and column like '%Z%'
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion sgmoore, but it doesnt satisfy my requirements. I am afraid but this seems to be partially correct suggestion. Using this method if my table "MyTable" has values in "MyColumn" as "John", "Joseph", "Philip" and my List<string> has an item with value as "ph" then it wont get me any records. It searches for entire value in List<string> item!

Comment: You should get two records returned ie Joseph and Philip. What sql is generated by your query?

Comment: it gives empty IEnumerable<> !. The recordset is empty.

Comment: I mean what sql commands are generated and sent to the sql server. You can see this if you look at the value of dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText