# Linq: CONTAINS with multiple dynamic input string values

Tags: c#, linq

I have similar requirement which is mentioned in below link with little tweak.

[LINQ : How to check CONTAINS with multiple dynamic input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382563/linq-how-to-check-contains-with-multiple-dynamic-input-values)

I gone through few links but couldn't find a solution. Please guide.

I receive the multiple selected `string` in the format as `selected = "Consumer,Business,Others"`. This I use them in below query:

```
var q = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where a.Field<string>("Period") == "Jan 2014" && a.Field<string>("Division").Contains(selected)
                select a;

        GridView1.DataSource = q.CopyToDataTable();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Though Database had data, q returns in null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] selectedList = selected.Split(',');
var q = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where a.Field<string>("Period") == "Jan 2014" && 
        selectedList.Contains(a.Field<string>("Division")) 
        select a;

GridView1.DataSource = q.CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Any suggestion, why the below code doesn't work for me? If the selectedAll contains selectedAll[0] = ""
`string[] selectedAll = All.Split(',');`

 `&& selectedAll.Contains(a.Field<double?>("All Impacted Hours").ToString())`

Comment: Are you sure the column name contains spaces (`All Impacted Hours`) ?

Comment: I'm using <double?> for handling NULL values

Comment: The source contains no DataRows.