# Multiple Values Contains with Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic-linq

How to use Multiple value with Contain in Dynamic Linq.

**Expected With Normal Linq :**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {
    string[] names = { "Burke", "Laptop", "Computer", 
                       "Mobile", "Ahemed", "Sania", 
                       "Kungada", "David","United","Sinshia" };
      string[] vars = {"i","a"};
      var query = names.Where(i=> vars.Any(j=>i.Contains(j))).ToList();

      Console.WriteLine(query.Count);
  }
}
```

**Expected SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE (NAME LIKE '%a%'OR NAME LIKE '%b%')
```

**Tried Dynamic Linq :**

```
query = query.Where("new[]{\"a\",\"c\"}.Any(i=>i.Contains(it.ProductName))");
```

**Returns Exception :**

```
No property or field 'ProductName' exists in type 'String'
```

Dependicies :

- .NET CORE 2.2
- EntityFramework Core 2.2.6
- System.Linq.Dynamic.Core 1.0.18
  (https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

Comment: doest it work ? `i=> i.Contains(vars.Any()))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your "tried dynamic query":

1. When translating to the dynamic query you have mixed the variable names, because `i` and `j` are too similar.
2. `it` is ambigous as there are 2 lambdas and so it is parsed as a parameter of the innermost lambda.

Let's first rename `i` to `p` (for "product names") and `j` to `s` (for "search"):

```
var query = names.Where(p => vars.Any(s => p.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

Then you can directly transform this to a dynamic Linq expression:

```
// The type of vars needs to be IEnumerable<string> otherwise Dynamic Linq does not see .Any
IEnumerable<string> vars = new[] {"i", "a"};
var query2 = names.Where("p => @0.Any(s => p.Contains(s))", vars).ToList();
```

Then you can replace the argument of inner lambda (s) with `it`

```
var query3 = names.Where("p => @0.Any(p.Contains(it))", vars).ToList();
```

As you can see you mixed up the object and argument of `Contains`.

Then you can apply the expression the EF query. So usage of argument `p` becomes `p.ProductName`:

```
IEnumerable<string> vars = new[] {"i", "a"};
query = query.Where("p => @0.Any(p.ProductName.Contains(it))", vars).ToList();
```

Or like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> vars = new[] {"i", "a"};
query = query.Where("p => @0.Any(s => p.ProductName.Contains(s))", vars).ToList();
```